# Meaning of "Rooting your device"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you explain to me please what [to root a device](http://www.androidpit.com/forum/636409/samsung-galaxy-s5-do-not-want-lolipop-how-can-i-stop-sprint-from-doing-an-ota) means?

> Well, there is no any way to disable the option of software update other than rooting your device.When an Android OS update is available for your device you will get a message stating so. It won't download automatically

Comment: This doesn't have much to do about English itself. This is a technical word meaning *to break the security locks and access home directories in your android*. That would render this question off-topic - It's like me coming and asking *what does hyperconjugation mean in this context?* While my context is chemistry-related. I'm waiting for the reaction of other guys towards this, so I won't VTC. But still, IMO this is off-topic. (Though you can see some connection to the verb "root" and its "technical use".)

Comment: See http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/root_2, senses 3 and 4.

Comment: Note that in Australian slang, *rooting* is an obscenity.

Comment: **Contexts**: compare with [the bounty-winning answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/202362/11504) to [Other ways to say “I'm rooting for you?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/36745/11504); "… (There are other meanings, of course. No one has yet mentioned … *I'm getting low-level access to your phone for you*.)".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though it is a technical term it has come into almost common parlance in recent years.

Its origins are far older than Android - stemming from the early 70s Bell Laboratories UNIX operating system.

The root user on a unix machine is the main administrator account; the one that can do absolutely anything.

In modern parlance that has come to mean to 'get below the regular user structure, to take over the machine at root level, in order to perform tasks not permitted to the regular user' & is now used in that context as a verb.

> I rooted my phone yesterday
>   I'm rooting my phone right now
>   I'm going to root my phone tomorrow

I guess it's going to be a pretty simple conjugation ;-)